# DBContext implementing Interface

Tags: entity-framework, user-interface, dbcontext

I have below codes in one compiled library

```
public interface IActivityLoggerContext
{
    DbSet<OF_Activities> OF_Activities { get; set; }
}



public partial class OF_Activities
{  
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public System.Guid ActivityID { get; set; }

    public int ModifiedBit { get; set; }
}
```

In my project I reference the above library and use it as shown below

```
public partial class OFrameEntities : DbContext, IActivityLoggerContext
{
    public OFrameEntities()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<BL_Categories> BL_Categories { get; set; } //model in this DBContext

    public virtual DbSet<OF_Activities> OF_Activities { get; set; } //Implementing the interface (IActivityLoggerContext) From the library

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }
}
```

Now everything works fine.

But the issue is that I am unable to extend or add extra properties to the OF_Activities class in my Project

What changes do i need to make so that my Context implements the Interface as well as I am able to extend the model

Comment: what does "unable" mean? are you getting an error when you add new properties to the OF_Activities class?

Comment: I hate partial classes they are designed for the user interface and whzen you use them, they give more complexity for the code and I donot know why the developers just use them everywhere!. back to your question do you have 2 models and you need to separate them in 2 classes or interfaces?

Comment: One model OF_Activities is in the library. 

Now in the Project I have referenced the library. 

Now in the project I  have another model with same name OF_Activities which i made to extend OF_Activities model from the library. I want to add extra properties to it. 

When i do it and in the OFrameEntities class when I change the DBSet to use the new extended model of OF_Activities it shows the interface not implemented error as the interface wants the OF_Activities of the library to be implemented and not the extended one.

Comment: then just use the bounded context. here is a good example https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883952.aspx read this and give me a feedback

Answer (score 0):

Your extended OF_Activities model needs to have the exact same namespace as the OF_Activities model in your library.

If the compiler is complaining that you haven't implemented IActivityLoggerContext it's probably because you've made a partial class called OF_Activities but not changed the namespace to match that of the library.

**Note**: You can only have a partial classes residing in the same dll. i.e. Any partial class extensions to your model will have to be present in the library.

You can still extend the class with extension methods if you are unable to place the extended model in the library.

Comment: My purpose is to make a separate dll for business logic and model and use it in whatever project i like. If i want i can further extend the functionality by extending the model and its logic in separate classes depending on the project. Now it is not necessary that i do it the way i have mentioned, but i want to achieve this thing if possible in a better way.